C# error "not all code paths return a value" ignoring string condition check
There are a number of similar questions on SO, and looking at those it always seems the asker has missed a path. But this one has got me stumped. In its simplest form:
public Object Test() {
    string testStr = "test";
    if (testStr != null) {
        return null;
    }
}

It's fine if the string is a const
public Object Test() {
    const string testStr = "test";
    if (testStr != null) {
        return null;
    }
}

Why does the compiler suggest that the value of testStr may be null (the value may change between the explicit setting and the condition check)?
(VS2022, .NET8, Nullable disabled)

Because when you declare a const compiler knows that at compile time that testStr always has a value of test and cannot be null, and this value cannot be changed during runtime- which doesnt apply to the non-const variable.
